# Rescript Record: Key as Array

Tags: reason, rescript

In Rescript, one can define a `Record` in this format:

```ml
type record1 = {
   a : String
}
```

but **NOT**:

```ml
type record2 = {
   [a] : String
}
```

I am looking to write a record that **compiles to** **JS** like:

```js
{
   [Op.or]: [12,13]
}
```

The use case above comes from `Sequelize`, and the reference is [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html).

My *current solution*:

```ml
%raw(`{[Op.or]:[12,13]}`)
```

Comment: They're called computed properties, and have nothing to do with arrays other than that they share a few lexical tokens. As far as I know the only alternative to using `%raw` is to use [`@set_index`](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/bind-to-js-object#bind-using-special-getter-and-setter-attributes)

Comment: Alternatively you can use [`Js.Dict.t`](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/api/js/dict), assuming the keys are strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear how you intend to interface with the `Op` construct, whether you can bind to it or not, but here's an example that does, and along with `Js.Dict.t` effectively produces the same output:

```ml
module Op = {
  @val external or: string = "Op.or"
}

Js.Dict.fromList(list{
  (Op.or, [12, 23])
})
```

It does not directly compile to the JS you want, however, which might be a problem if you rely on something that actually parses the source code. But short of that, I believe this should do what you ask for.